# $\frac{\chi(e)}{|G|}\sum_{h\in G}\chi(hg)\overline{\chi(h)}=\chi(g)$

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I want to prove that $\frac{\chi(e)}{|G|}\sum_{h\in G}\chi(hg)\overline{\chi(h)}=\chi(g)$. This is needed to prove that $\frac{\chi(e)}{|G|}\sum_{h\in G}\chi(h^{-1})h\in K[G]$ is an idempotent. I don't know which is easier to prove.

Sorry, forgot to mention $\chi$ is an irreducible character of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easier to prove your second sum is an idempotent.
By the orthogonality property of characters, it acts as the identity on
an irreducible module with character $\chi$, and as zero on any irreducible
module with any other character. Applying it twice to any representation
is the same as applying it once. Considering the regular representation
shows it's an idempotent.